# Mod Rewrite, pass parameters from URL1 to URL2

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to rewrite the following URL

```
test.php?par1=foo&par2=bar
```

Into...

```
newtest.php?hidden_par=blah&par1=foo&par2=bar
```

I have this rule, that does not work:

```
RewriteRule ^test.php\??(.*?)$ newtest.php?hiden_par=blah&$1 [L]
```

Could this be done using RewriteCond or something else? (say, could this be done ?), thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You probably want something like the `QSA` ("query string append") flag, which causes the remainder of the query string to be properly appended onto the end of the rewritten URL.

For example:

```
^test.php test.php?hidden=value [L,QSA]
```