# Rewrite URL with .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

How do I redirect

```
    <http://coralpoolsupplies.com/temp33/default.aspx?PID=26&DID=1101>
```

to

```
    <http://coralpoolsupplies.com/qualifications>
```

My current htaccess is as follows:

```
    <RewriteEngine on 
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} PID=26
    RewriteRule ^temp33/default\.aspx$ /qualifications/? [R=301]>
```

Comment: What is location of above .htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

check this answer:
[Mod Rewrite, pass parameters from URL1 to URL2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/639869/mod-rewrite-pass-parameters-from-url1-to-url2)

You need to add the `QSA` flag in order to pass the query parameters.

Try something like:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} PID=26
RewriteRule ^/temp33/default\.aspx /qualifications/ [R=301,QSA]
```